# systemd : get status of target's sub jobs

Tags: systemd, debian-stretch

**TLDR**

How do I get a view of the status of all services on a target ?

something like :

```
# obviously, 'systemctl status' does not have this output :
$ systemctl --user status service.target
service.target: inactive (dead)
├── backend.service:  active
├── db.service: active
├── frontend.service: active
└── scheduler.service: inactive (dead)
```

**Context**

We have several systemd units, which are parts of a more global service, so we have written a `service.target` with all these units as dependencies.

For a more complete context :

1. the units and target are actually user units and target units
2. the `service.target`file consists only of a description :

   ```
   #cat .config/systemd/user/service.target
   [Unit]
   Description = Service global target
   ```
3. `service.target`'s dependencies are listed in the filesystem :

   ```
   $ tree .config/systemd/user
   ├── backend.service
   ├── db.service
   ├── frontend.service
   ├── scheduler.service
   ├── service.target
   └── service.target.requires
      ├── backend.service -> ../backend.service
      ├── db.service -> ../db.service
      ├── frontend.service -> ../frontend.service
      └── scheduler.service -> ../scheduler.service
   ```

With this setup, `systemctl --user start service.target` and `systemctm --user stop service.target` works like we expect.

**What I would like**

I would like to have a command or a script, which would tell me wether the dependencies of the target are all up, only partially up, or all down.

From what I tried :

- `systemctl --user status service.target` will correctly tell me (and exit with `0`) if all services are up, but will not help me to distinguish between "some are up, some are down" and "all are down" (in both case : exit code is `3`, status message says `inactive (dead)`)
- `systemctl --user list-dependencies service.target` does not give an output stable enough to parse
- `systemctl --user status` will give me a detailed overview of all processes started by systemd  user services, but I d'ont know how to narrow this list down to "only the services under service.target"

**Question**

What is the most stable way to get the status of all the services on which a systemd target depends ?

Should we modify our setup ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This topic was recently discussed in [How to create a virtual systemd service to stop/start several instances together?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/283714/how-to-create-a-virtual-systemd-service-to-stop-start-several-instances-together).

The summary of options is:

1. `systemctl status $(systemctl list-dependencies --plain your.target)`
2. [Comment on the systemd feature request to add this as a built-in feature](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/9273)

Comment: For a more compact status output, try `systemctl list-units $(systemctl list-dependencies --plain your.target)`

Comment: See also `systemctl --user show --property=ConsistsOf your.target`

Comment: As of systemd v245 there's the `--with-dependencies` option: `systemctl status --with-dependencies your.target`

Answer (score 1):

While poking around systemd, I found the following command gives me a more direct list of the services I want to inspect :

```
systemctl --user show --property=ConsistsOf your.target
```

It has the added benefit of returning `""` on base services :

```
$ systemctl --user show --property=ConsistsOf service.target
ConsistsOf=backend.service db.service frontend.service scheduler.service
$ systemctl --user show --property=ConsistsOf backend.service
ConsistsOf=
```

---

@MarkStosberg commented (correctly) that :

1. It's not alphabetical
2. The `ConsistsOf=` at the beginning requires some form of stripping anyway before passing it to another command

The benefits I see are :

1. It only lists items which are declared as `PartOf` of my target :
   for example when I use `list-dependencies` on `db.service`, I see :

   ```
   $ systemctl --user list-dependencies --plain db.service
   db.service
     -.slice
     basic.target
     paths.target
     sockets.target
     dirmngr.socket
     gpg-agent-browser.socket
     gpg-agent-extra.socket
     gpg-agent-ssh.socket
     gpg-agent.socket
     timers.target
   ```

   (which is technically true, but irrelevant for my use case) while :

   ```
   $ systemctl --user show --property=ConsistsOf db.service
   ConsistsOf=
   ```

   does show an empty list
2. I didn't state it in my original question, but we actually use some extra parameters (`backend.service` can actually be `backend@p0.service` or `backend@p1.service` or ...)
   When using `list-dependencies` on our target, somehow, `backend@p0.service` gets listed twice :

   ```
   $ systemctl --user list-dependencies --plain service.target
   service.target
     backend@p0.service
     backend@p0.service
     db.service
     frontend.service
     scheduler.service
   ```
3. the unit itself is listed in `list-dependencies`, but not in `ConsistsOf`

So I had to apply some processing on the output anyway.

Just sharing my experience ; thanks for your answer and indications which pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: For targets, this is not more-direct than `systemctl list-dependencies --plain`, it it is exactly the same list of dependencies, 1. It's not alphabetical. 2. It includes "ConsistsOf=" at the beginning, so the output can't be directly passed to another command  without first stripping this out.  This variation could be useful when there is a difference between the "dependencies" and the "ConsistsOf" values.